# Are rectangles fixed height in RDLC reports?

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I have an RDLC report with a sub-report that I want to be A4 paper in height. The number of rows in the sub-report may vary, so I placed the sub-report in a rectangle so that if the sub-report is short the rest of my report doesn't shrink. According to the documentation rectangles are fixed size. This works fine when I show the report on a web page, but when I run it in a ReportViewer in a WinForms app it shrinks!

Is this a known problem and does anyone have any ideas about what to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six minutes later, I find the answer to my own question...

By default the `ReportViewer` is displaying the report in **Normal** mode - (which looks wrong to my mind).  Setting it to **Page Layout** mode corrects the problem.

In **VB.NET** this was done with:

```
Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set all textbox CanGrow is False, then rectangles are fixed size